# Error while creating a new app in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, create-react-app

PS D:\React\counter-app> create-react-app tower
create-react-app : File C:\Users\ee209495\AppData\Roaming\npm\create-react-app.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. 
For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1
+ create-react-app tower
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess

Answer (score 0):

Try executing the console with admin credentials.
You might not have permissons while trying to execute npm commands.
i would also recommend to use npx create-reaact-app myapp.
This provides a previous check to see if you had already installed react packages, if not, it will install them for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try following steps:

1. Go to Start Menu and search for "Windows PowerShell ISE".
2. Right click the x86 version and choose "Run as administrator".
3. In the top part, paste `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned;` run the script. Choose "Yes".
4. Repeat these steps for the 64-bit version of Powershell ISE too (the non x86 version).

Comment: After doing the above method. Getting the error like this: D:\React>npm start
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path D:\React\package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\React\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ee209495\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-05-28T16_46_42_647Z-debug.log

Comment: Are you inside the directory in whihc `package.json`is present?
The error clearly states it is unable to find `package.json`

Answer (score 0):

this problem because of security feature in your system.
 1. Open powershell as an administrator.
 2. Run the following command set-executionpolicy remotesigned
 3. Try again.

Answer (score 0):

The error "create-react-app.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system" occurs when the execution policy does not allow running the specific script on Windows.

Use the `Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned` command to solve the error.

Open your PowerShell as an administrator and set its execution policy with the `Set-ExecutionPolicy` command.

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

The `Set-ExecutionPolicy` command sets the PowerShell execution policy for the Windows computer.

If you aren't able to run the command as an administrator, try running it with the `CurrentUser` parameter.

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser
```

The `RemoteSigned` policy still prevents us from running unsigned scripts.
Now, run the `Get-ExecutionPolicy` command:

```
Get-ExecutionPolicy
```

The `Get-ExecutionPolicy` command should display the effective execution policy for the current PowerShell session (`RemoteSigned`).

[image]